# Getting exceptions (Missing descriptor / No [EntityType] was found for the key class) on the below scenario

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, weblogic, eclipselink, jta

**Getting exceptions (Missing descriptor / No [EntityType] was found for the key class) on below scenario.**

1. Start the weblogic server
2. Deploy the WAR
3. Test the application ‘n’ of times
4. Delete the WAR from web logic admin console
5. Re deploy the same WAR

Basically, if we do redeploy we will got the above exception. This issue will get resolved if you restart the server.

Persistence.xml

```
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <jta-data-source>DEV</jta-data-source>

    <class>com.Class1</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.allow-zero-id" value="true"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
        <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="WebLogic"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.query.timeout" value="120000"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.lock.timeout" value="120000"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

### Bean Configuration to handle spring transaction

```
   <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">    
          <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
          <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager" />              
   </bean>

   <bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
          <list>
          <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
   <property name="loadTimeWeaver" ref="loadTimeWeaver"/>
 </bean>

<bean id="loadTimeWeaver" class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.weblogic.WebLogicLoadTimeWeaver"/>

   <bean id="em" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
   <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
   </bean>
```

Comment: How are you obtaining your EntityManagers and factories, and more importantly, how are you closing them?  This error occurs when you redeploy but the old factory is still open, allowing the old factory (and its classloaders) to be used in the current application.  Closing the old factories will allow a new one created for the new application.

Comment: Chris, we used the springs to handle the EntityManager, factories and Transactions. We thought that Container itself will open, load and close the EM, Factory and Transactions, is their any configuration involved to close the old factories ?

Comment: Chris, attached spring JTA configuration above, could you help us to resolve the problem.?

Answer (score 0):

The WL Server throwing this error because of the ServerSession is cached in the EntityManagerSetupImpl static, so on createEntityManagerFactory() the old one is used with the old descriptors/class before the redeployment.

**

> We managed to take the EntityManagerFactory Object and closed the same
>   in the destroy method in one of the InitializerServlet.

**